# Any PDF reader which remembers at which page the document was opened last time?

Tags: pdf, ebook, adobe-reader

Do you know any PDF reader which remembers the last page for each document?

The usage scenario should be something like this:

- A new PDF file is loaded into the reader
- The PDF file is opened on page 0
- Reading, reading, reading ... Reading finished at page 37.
- Reader closed
  ...
- The same PDF file is loaded into the reader
- The PDF File is opened on page 37

I don't need multiple bookmarks. Just one is enough. Any tips?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Acrobat Reader

[image]

Comment: doesn't work for some odd reason

Comment: Does not work for me either.

Comment: It used to work just fine, but seems to be broken at the moment. Switching to another PDF reader might be your best option, as Adobe is notorious for ignoring wishes and complaints by customers (have a quick look at their forums if you don't believe me).

Answer (score 9):

[**Foxit Reader**](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/reader/reader3.php) does that and it's free!

[image]

Comment: The page gets saved for a little while only, if i open the book some months later, it forgets the page. Any tips on that?

Comment: Maybe by increasing the maximum number of documents in the history list?

Answer (score 5):

[Evince](http://projects.gnome.org/evince/) does that...it's for Linux, but hey you never said anything about the OS: ;)

Comment: Unfortunately in depends. If evince is compiled without gvfs-support it does not remembers the history or last opened page.

Answer (score 4):

**[PDF-Xchange Viewer](http://www.docu-track.com/home/prod_user/PDF-XChange_Tools/pdfx_viewer/)** does just that (and not only for the last opened document, but all documents). In addition you can create your own bookmarks.

[image]

PDF-Xchange Viewer is freeware and a portable version is available.

Answer (score 4):

[Sumatra](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) does that to all PDF files by default.

> Sumatra PDF is a free PDF, XPS, DjVu, CHM, Comic Book (CBZ and CBR)
>   reader for Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Since no OS is mentioned: Preview on Mac OS X does it by default.

Answer (score 2):

[Okular](http://okular.kde.org/)