# Evince in WSL2 doesn't remember last visited page

Tags: pdf, wsl2, evince, gvfs

I use the Evince pdf reader on WSL2, but it isn't remembering the last visited page. Every time I open a pdf file, it starts from the first page in a small window with the message:

```
chen@4-726:~/Documents/latex/notes/physics/tokamak$ Gdk-Message: 11:43:25.750: Unable to load hand2 from the cursor theme
Gdk-Message: 11:43:25.925: Unable to load hand2 from the cursor theme
Gdk-Message: 11:43:26.153: Unable to load hand2 from the cursor theme
```

I read a [post](https://superuser.com/a/777148/1697720) saying that evince should store reading histories in `~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home`, but I don't see folder `gvfs-metadata` in WSL2.

Then [another comment](https://superuser.com/a/99153/1697720) says:

> If evince is compiled without gvfs-support it does not remembers the history or last opened page.

So how can I get gvfs-support for WSL2 and make Evince remember reading history?

---

**ps** my system inforation

All my system seems to have the newest version:

```
Device name 1-039-11
Processor AMD Ryzen 9 5900X 12-Core Processor 3.70 GHz
Installed RAM 32.0 GB
Device ID D3418E8A-2C8C-4EC2-A836-7ABF7E5D9D51
Product ID 00330-71450-76029-AAOEM
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch No pen or touch input is available for this display

Edition Windows 11 Pro
Version 21H2
Installed on ‎1/‎11/‎2022
OS build 22000.708
Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22000.708.0

Linux 1-039-11 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Mar 2 00:30:59 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               chen@1-039-11 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ------------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on Windows 10 x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Kernel: 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Uptime: 20 hours, 28 mins 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Packages: 1922 (dpkg) 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Shell: bash 5.1.16 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Adwaita [GTK3] 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Icons: Adwaita [GTK3] 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   Terminal: terminator 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 5900X (24) @ 3.700GHz 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   GPU: 3448:00:00.0 Microsoft Corporation Device 008e 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Memory: 529MiB / 15952MiB 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+                             
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/                              
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

Comment: You've done some good research there.  The gvfs hint is almost certainly the key.  I should be able to test and write up an answer for you fairly soon.

Comment: You don't mention your Linux distribution, though.  I'm going to assume Ubuntu, but it's best to include that information (and your Windows version) in WSL questions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

###### Short answer:

Assuming that you are using Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install gvfs
dbus-launch evince <file.pdf>
```

Scroll to a location in the PDF, then exit Evince and:

```
dbus-launch evince <file.pdf>
```

It should now open to the previous location.

###### More detail:

You are absolutely right that Evince uses GVfs (the Gnome Virtual File System) to store its bookmarks.

There are a few reasons why this doesn't work (by default) on WSL:

- GVfs isn't installed by default on most WSL distributions.
- GVfs requires a user-session D-Bus instance.  D-Bus is, to take the simple definition from a [much more complicated page](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/):

  > a simple way for applications to talk to one another

  > makes it simple and reliable to code a "single instance" application or daemon, and to launch applications and daemons on demand when their services are needed

  So Evince uses D-Bus to launch-or-attach-to a single instance of the GVfs daemon, and then uses GVfs to store the bookmark.
- But that D-Bus instance is normally set up for you by Systemd (and/or PAM) on login.
- And WSL doesn't really have the concept of a "login" (you typically never need to enter a password when starting WSL). WSL also [doesn't support Systemd out of the box](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379567/1165986).

All of this combines to mean that (in a default WSL installation) Evince isn't going to keep track of your last location/bookmark.

Installing GVfs is the first step.

Then, you have two options:

- `dbus-launch evince` each time you start, as in the example above.
- Or, when you start WSL, use:

  ```
  wsl ~ -e dbus-launch bash # Or your preferred shell
  ```

  That will start your Bash shell in a D-Bus user session, and then simply doing `evince <file.pdf>` will open to the last location.

You can see some of what is happening by running `ps -efH` between each command.  You'll see that `dbus-launch bash` will start a D-Bus process, but not much else.  Then running `evince` will also start up on-demand GVfs processes.