# Evince with dbus-launch cann't use WSL2 input methods

Tags: pdf, wsl2, pdf-reader, evince

In the first post i asked [how to enable reading history of Evince in WSL2](https://superuser.com/q/1724959/1697720), thanks to [the answer](https://superuser.com/a/1724987/1697720) which recommends:

```
dbus-launch evince <file.pdf>
```

But I found a problem, I cannot use `WSL2` input methods in PDF search anymore (for example I use `fcitx5` as input method).

I can still use `fcitx5` in the old method to open a PDF without history.

```
evince <file.pdf>
```

So how could I use `fcitx5` in `Evince` with the `dbus-launch` command?

p.s. [how to install and use `fcitx5` in WSL2 (partially solved)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1389040/1286546)

Comment: Hmm - How did you go about installing fcitx5 under WSL?  It's been a while since I tried it.  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds It's another headache for me, to install is relatively easy, but auto start is not been solved, see my full description in this post https://askubuntu.com/a/1389040/1286546

Answer (score 0):

I have to say I'm currently at a loss on this one after spending some time attempting to get fcitx5 running.  I just don't understand the input method controls well enough to get it running under WSLg and then work on troubleshooting the `evince` problem.

The best I can do is offer a few possibilities that I can't test:

- Try running `WAYLAND_DISPLAY= dbus-launch evince <pdf>`:  By default, Evince runs under Wayland if it is available.  This command will force Evince to run under X by making it think that Wayland isn't there.  I know your `fcitx5` answer mentioned having to disable Wayland for it, so I'm wondering if you need to do so for Evince as well.
- Try running *everything* in a WSL session starting with `wsl ~ -e dbus-launch bash`.  I know I mentioned this option in my other Evince answer, but your question here doesn't mention it.  Both Evince and fcitx5 utilize D-bus, and I'm wondering if there's some conflict happening in the separate launches.
- Also try combining the above two attempts by starting WSL with `wsl ~ -d dbus-launch bash` and then starting Evince with simply `WAYLAND_DISPLAY= evince <pdf>`.